# let X1 and X2 be subspaces of R given by: X1 = (0,1) U (3, 4) and X2 = (0,1) U (1, 2) Is X1 homeomorphic to X2?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question :

let X1 and X2 be subspaces of R given by:

X1 = (0,1) U (3, 4)  and X2 = (0,1) U (1, 2)

Is X1 homeomorphic to X2?

I was thinking about connectedness if one is connected and the second is not then it is not homeomorphic. but here both are disconnected. can you give me a hint how to think about it?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in (0,1)\\ x-2 & x \in (3,4)\end{cases}$$

is a homeomorphism from $X_1$ onto $X_2$...